# What is the dual space of $C[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I want to know more about $BV[0,1]$. Like the way a function in $BV[0,1]$ acts on $C[0,1]$, and when a sequence in $C[0,1]$ is weakly convergence?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiMjcyx9OfrAhXlILcAHU6QD80QFjASegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjfr.unibo.it%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F1952%2F1538&usg=AOvVaw234rhPDf2OC9kauRDJcI2H

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $f_n \in C[0,1]$ is weakly convergent to $f\in C[0,1]$ if and only if for any $g\in BV[0,1]$ we have $$\int_0^1 (f_n (u) - f(u) )dg(u) \to 0 $$ as $n\to \infty.$

Where the above integral is a $Riemman-Stielties $ integral.